# Displaying Social Security Number with Dashes in Combo Box in Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, input-mask

I have a Social Security field that has an input mask - input mask in table and input mask on field. If I display the field in a form, it shows the dashes.  When I put a combo box, the values in the combo box do not show dashes, but when I pick one, it does show the dashes. How can I show the dashes in the values of the combo box?  I have searched for this and am coming up empty.  You think someone would have wanted this at some time???  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If this is not for homework, putting SSNs in Access will leave your company open to all kinds of headache in regards to data privacy laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have add a field/column to the source of the combobox, and display this.

Create it like:

```
TextSSN: Format([SSN], "YourFormatString")
```